# How to handle if CompletableFuture might be null on occasions

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I have these CompletableFutures:

```
CompletableFuture<Info> futureA =
    createFutureA(multipleItems, startDate, source, context);

CompletableFuture<PPPInfo> futureB =
    createFutureB(multipleItems, startDate, source, context);

CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureA, futureB);
```

`futureA` calls `createFutureA` which can be seen below:

```
private CompletableFuture<PPPInfo> createFutureA(
      MultipleItems multipleItems,
      String startDate,
      Source source,
      Context context) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () ->
            getItemAPrice(
                Double.parseDouble(multiplePrices.getItemA().getPrice()),
                startDate,
                source,
                ITEMA,
                context));
}
```

There are some occasions where `multiplePrices.getItemA()` is `null` which causes a `NullPointerException` in `createFutureA` and is an issue when the application then calls `combinedFuture.get()`. How should I handle this if I might have occasions where `futureA` is null?

Comment: So your problem is that `getItemA()` can return `null`. The solution is either, to fix the method to not return `null` or fix the caller to not invoke `getPrice()` unconditionally on a reference that might be `null`. In either case, it’s entirely unrelated to the fact that you’re using the code together with `CompletableFuture`. You would have the same problem if you were not using `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle null inside `createFutureA`.

If `multiplePrices.getItemA()` is a regular (synchronous) function, something like below would work.

```java
private CompletableFuture<PPPInfo> createFutureA(
      MultipleItems multipleItems,
      String startDate,
      Source source,
      Context context) {
    Item itemA = multiplePrices.getItemA();
    if (itemA == null) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () ->
            getItemAPrice(
                Double.parseDouble(itemA.getPrice()),
                startDate,
                source,
                ITEMA,
                context));
}
```

If `multiplePrices.getItemaA()` is also an async function, returning a completable future, something like below would work.

```java
private CompletableFuture<PPPInfo> createFutureA(
      MultipleItems multipleItems,
      String startDate,
      Source source,
      Context context) {
    return multiplePrices.getItemA()
        .thenApply(itemA => {
            if (itemA == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return getItemAPrice(
                Double.parseDouble(itemA.getPrice()),
                startDate,
                source,
                ITEMA,
                context);
        });
}
```